# "Api enabled" permission necessary for fetching record type dependent picklist data

Tags: apex, rest-api, dependent-picklist

In my project we dont have "API enabled" for any user, as its a secure system.

Now we have a custom form in Omniscript, which needs to display controlling and dependent picklist values based on record type.
So we decided to use `/ui-api/object-info/{objectApiName}/picklist-values/{recordTypeId}/{fieldApiName}`

Now though this is internal api each user must have API Enabled access to fetch it

As its a secure system and `API Enabled` permission cannot be given, is there a way we can define a named credential and use a single user to do all the callouts?

Also would this user also need object and field permissions in order to do the callouts or only API enabled is enough and FLS needs to be only with the user who initated this api?